# Is there windows Bluray player software that runs on wine in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wine, blu-ray

I'm looking for bluray player software that I can run through wine in Ubuntu 13.10. I don't mind paid software.

The reason I'm looking for WINE and not native is that, as far as I can tell, there are no native blueray players that can play the newest bluray disks.

Thanks!

EDIT 1: I'm not interested in ripping bluray, just playing them. Yes, I know if you can read it you can rip it, but I just want to clear on my end goal.

EDIT 2: I've gotten some blurays to work through makeMKV (e.g. Monsters University), but Newer disks like The Hobbit (Extended edition) are not viewable.

Comment: Why does it have to be through Wine ? Also, have a look at http://www.thelinuxcauldron.com/2014/01/05/a-guide-to-playing-blu-rays-on-ubuntu-linux/ and

Comment: My understanding was there were no commercial players for linux. By that, I mean I can play a newly released bluray. I'll check out your options and report back.

Answer (score 0):

MacGo Windows Blu Ray Player works very well under Wine. I have used it on Ubuntu till now. I don't really know why nobody apart me is using it. Only issue: you have to register it but is has an acceptable price.